# For what used for empty function how second argument in then (promise.then)?

Tags: javascript, function, promise

I find in big project some code:

```
const handlePay = () => {
    someFunction()
      .then(unwrapResult)
      .then(
        () => history.push(
          authorizedRoutes.accruals.payment.link
        ),
        () => {} /* what is it??? */
      );
```

I dont understand for what this code: `() => {}`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then: "it takes up to two arguments: callback functions for the success **and failure** cases".

Comment: It's silently failing. Never do it

Comment: the second argument defines what to do in case of failure, while `() => {}` is just an empty function. So it means "in case of any problem, don't notify, don't print anything, just proceeds like nothing happened"

Comment: thx Cristian Traìna

Answer (score 0):

Here is a closer look at `.then()`

```
p.then(function(value) {
   // fulfillment
  }, function(reason) {
  // rejection
});
```

Its the reject

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Comment: I ask why this func is empty. My quest: "For what used for !!!!! EMPTY !!!! function how second argument in 'then'?"

Comment: @RomaN usually you catch some error and then do something with it. Like display to the user or some other stuff. In this case, its silent. It means: When it throws an error the function gets triggered but it does nothing. And your user on the frontend or you as developer will have a hard time to debugg if there appear some error

Comment: Cristian Traìna answer: "the second argument defines what to do in case of failure, while () => {} is just an empty function. So it means "in case of any problem, don't notify, don't print anything, just proceeds like nothing happened"